# How to reference an image file in a SwiftUI iPad Playground?

Tags: image, ipad, swiftui, swift-playground

I have added an image (jpg) from my Photo Album to the UserResources folder (via the + menu in the upper right of the Playground app). How do I reference that file when declaring a SwiftUI Image?

I have tried using the entire path:

```
let path: String = { Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "JPG", inDirectory: nil)[0] }()
```

It seems to give me the path to the desired file, “PICT0024.JPG”:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/F01FA67E-97CA-4590-915A-C8071507C6E0/Library/Application Support/Main Module Resources Bundles/55929C8C-46C9-4691-B86B-389D1473E9A8.bundle/Contents/Resources/PICT0024.JPG
```

I then declare:

```
Image(systemName: path)
```

But the image is not shown. I probably have the wrong reference, but cannot figure out what I need to specify.

Oh, just this

```
Image(“PICT0024.JPG”)
```

doesn’t work either.

What is the proper way to reference that image file?

Please confine answers to SwiftUI 5 and editing on an iPad. Using XCode at the moment isn’t an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `Image(systemName: path)`

this constructor one is for system SF Symbols

> `Image(“PICT0024.JPG”)`

this constructor is for images in Assets catalog

The external images you have to use like this

`Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: path))`

Comment: Just discovered that ```Image(uiImage: (UIImage(named: "PICT0024.JPG")!))``` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

// Add image to the project with the "+" button,
// then select either the file, or image icon,
// then navigate to desired image, 
// then add it to the iPad Playground project

let imageFileNameString = "IMG_2702.jpeg"


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // the method below requires the UIImage be unwrapped
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: imageFileNameString)!) 

        //   -or-
        
        // The commented-out method below does not require any unwrapping. 
        // Typos will fail with "something went wrong around here" error

        // Image(uiImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: imageFileNameString))
            
        .resizable()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView( ContentView() )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:
https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-swift-playgrounds-ipad-mac/

[Edit by original poster]
Summarizing from the article (worth a read because it discusses far more than how to access an image resource), here’s how to do it:

1. Type `Image.` and using the autocomplete bar, pick the moon and mountains icon (ImageLiteral)

[image: image Literal icon]

2. That displays the “Images” popup. If you have not already added an image, choose either “Insert From...“, “Photo Library”, or “Take Photo”. Once you add an image, select it and press, “Use” (upper right corner of popover).

The result looks like this:

[image]

[The image here is of buttercups, *Ranunculus acris*.]